# Vector rotation in the $xy$-plane

Tags: linear-algebra

If multiplication by the matrix $A$ rotates a vector $x$ in the $xy$-plane through an angle $\theta$ what is the effect of multiplying $x$ by $A^T$?

Comment: If A is a rotation, A is an orthogonal matrix.  In which case $A^T = A^{-1}$

Comment: The fact that $A$ is orthogonal means that $AA^{-1}=I$ which means you just rotate the vector back to the start position by multiplying with $A^T$. Right?

Comment: $A^TA = I$ yes, it is a rotation in the opposite direction.